# New Android Studio 2.2 does not work on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: android

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

I downloaded and extracted ZIP of Android Studio 2.2 Prev 1. I am using Ubuntu on my system and on opening studio.sh using terminal i received this message:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this 
!/bin/sh

to
!/bin/bash

Android Studio 2.2 should launch

Comment: That's the curse of just letting /bin/sh be a symlink to /bin/bash. People add bash-specific features to their scripts without realizing it.

Comment: To anyone who might be wondering, the file to change is in `bin/studio.sh` -- also, you can avoid changing it by just `cd`ing to `/bin` and then type `bash studio.sh`